# Large install file without additional Bin Files

Tags: inno-setup

I learned about `DiskSpanning` and that it is required for larger file sizes. I however just want to compile my files into a single installation file. What I got was an application installer and 9 bin files of 2Gb each.

Is it possible to have all this contained into a single installer?

I am attempting to take several game pak files and create an installer with them.

```
[Setup]
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
DiskSpanning=yes
SlicesPerDisk=1
DiskSliceSize=max
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

The [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_diskspanning) says:

> Note that it is required that you set this directive to yes if the compressed size of your installation exceeds 2,100,000,000 bytes, even if you don't intend to place the installation onto multiple disks.

2 GB is also the [maximum size you can get per file](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_diskslicesize).

> Valid values: 262144 through 2100000000, or max

If you're worried that someone might miss copying some files, you might try a self extracting ZIP archive, e.g. using [7zip SFX Builder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was looking at the documentation further and I was curious if you could explain this to me.


-DiskSpanning=yes
-DiskSliceSize=max
-SlicesPerDisk=10

If the max size of a Slice is 2GB but a disk can have up to 26 Slices. ![SlicesPerDisk](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_diskspanning)

Would I still not be able to just have 1 disk with many slices?

Comment: @SpencerWennermark: yes, you can have 1 disk with 26 files à 2 GB each, so you can fill a  52 GB Blue Ray disk. It's still 26 files, though. I seemed to me you wanted 1 file only.

Comment: Thanks again, I understand now. I realized what I wanted to do and how it's done. Essentially I need to create a Launcher with an install file that contains a script that will pull the other files from a remote location. This is for a game and I didnt realize how it was done by publishers. 

</br>
I have spent all night reading and researching this topic and learned a great deal. Thank you again for your time.